# Where does the second total derivative live?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $f:M \to \mathbb{R} $ be a smooth function.  Then the total derivative of $f$ is a function on the tangent bundle:

$Df: TM \to \mathbb{R}$

Locally $TM$ is just the product of an open subset of $M$ with the tangent space of $M$. So, to compute $Df$, we pick a point on M, a direction in the tangent space at that point, and we output a real number.

Continuing in this manner, we can look at the total derivative of the total derivative:

$D^{2}(f) = D(D(f)):T(TM) \to \mathbb{R}$

Let $m = dim M$. Then $T(TM))$ has dimension $4m$.  This is what is confusing me, because it seems like the second derivative should live in a space of dimension $3m$.  One should be able to pick a point of the manifold, and two directions in the tangent space, and output a number.

Whereas here, to compute $D^{2}(f)$, it seems like we have to input an extra $m$ coordinates. We must choose a point on the manifold, a direction in the tangent space - this gives us our point $(x,v)$ on the manifold $TM$, and we want to compute the total derivative of the function $Df$.  Then we pick a direction in the tangent space $T_{(x,v)}(TM)$, say $w \in T_{(x,v)}(TM)$. But $w$ lives in a space of dimensinon $2m$, not of dimension $m$.

So, just where does $D^{2}(f)$ live?  Along the lines of the discussion above, one would be led to say $D^{2}(f) \in T^{*}(TM)$.  Is this correct?

If so, and if we are led to agree that the notion of a connection rectifies this conundrum, then where does the extraneous data go? As in, we've gone from dimension $4m$ to dimension $3m$, so what happened to the extra $m$ coordinates?

Comment: In local coordinates, something in $TTM$ looks like ($x^{i}, \partial_{j},\partial_{k}, \partial_{\partial_{l}})$, where each $i, j, k, l$ varies from 1 to $dim M$.  So we can write down the formula for the second differential in terms of these and everything makes sense in the usual way.   I think the "extra $m$ coordinates" are accounted for by repeated use of the first partials (the middle two coordinates, $\partial_{j}$ and $\partial_{k}$).

Comment: Also why would it be $m^4$ and not $4m$ ?

Comment: Edited, thank you.

Comment: Sure :). I also think your argumentation is sound and you kind of did give a big junk of a possible answer yourself. I do believe that $D^2(f)$ can be viewed to be in $T^*(TM)$. I also find the dimension stuff a bit confusion. But I think in terms of the tangent bundle the factor two comes in by choice to use a disjoint union for all tangent spaces, right? So, maybe what your feeling is, that $D^2(f)$ should depend on "three inputs" and as your argued that is also the case. As pointed out by ZxJx this extra coordinate is more or less a repetition (again by how $TTM$ is constructed). I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M$ be a two dimensional manifold with local coordinates $x,y$. The coordinates give a local trivialisation of the tangent bundle and the tangent tangent bundle (and the tangent tangent tangent bundle, ...) and let $dx, dy$ and $\partial x, \partial y$ be coordinates of two different tangent vectors at $(x,y)$ and let $\partial dx,\partial dy$ be coordinates of a vertical second order tangent vector ("acceleration vector") at $(x,y,dx,dy)$.

For a function $f(x,y)$ on $M$ the first differential is
$$
Df = f_xdx+f_ydy
$$
and the second differential becomes
$$
D^2f = f_{xx}\partial xdx+f_{xy}\partial ydx+f_{xy}\partial xdy+f_{yy}\partial ydy+f_x\partial dx+f_y\partial dy
$$
So the second differential takes as input a point $(x,y)$, two tangent vectors $(dx, dy)$ and $(\partial x, \partial y)$ and an acceleration vector $(\partial dx,\partial dy)$.

A connection is a specification of how the acceleration vector is linearly computed from the the two tangent vectors and the acceleration then gets defined as
\begin{align*}
\partial dx &= -(\Gamma_{11}^1\partial xdx+\Gamma_{12}^1\partial ydx+\Gamma_{21}^1 \partial xdy+\Gamma_{22}^1\partial ydy)\\
\partial dy &= -(\Gamma_{11}^2\partial xdx+\Gamma_{12}^2\partial ydx+\Gamma_{21}^2 \partial xdy+\Gamma_{22}^2\partial ydy)
\end{align*}

Comment: So what I was thining of as "extra information" was not extra at all; i.e., we do need to input two tangent vectors.